# Merging by group between dates with conditional repetition

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am asking for assistance on a particular merging problem using data.table.

Here is the example data:

```
library(data.table)


# Create example dataset
DT_A = data.table(
  Store = "A",
  Date = as.Date(sprintf("10-%02d-%02d", c(22:25, 26:28), rep(1:2, 4:3)),
    '%m-%d-%y')
)

DT_B = data.table(
  Store = "B",
  Date = as.Date(sprintf("10-%02d-%02d", c(22:25, 26:28), rep(1:2, 4:3)),
                 '%m-%d-%y')
)

DT <- rbindlist(list(DT_A, DT_B))


DT
    Store       Date
 1:     A 2001-10-22
 2:     A 2001-10-23
 3:     A 2001-10-24
 4:     A 2001-10-25
 5:     A 2002-10-26
 6:     A 2002-10-27
 7:     A 2002-10-28
 8:     B 2001-10-22
 9:     B 2001-10-23
10:     B 2001-10-24
11:     B 2001-10-25
12:     B 2002-10-26
13:     B 2002-10-27
14:     B 2002-10-28
```

So, `DT`, has observations of store A and B across multiple dates.

I have another dataset, `manager_DT` say, that has the start and end dates of managers:

```
manager_DT <- data.table(Manager = c("John", "David", "Steve"),
                         Store = c("A", "A","B"),
                         min_date = c(as.Date("2001-10-22"),
                                      as.Date("2001-10-26"),
                                      as.Date("2001-10-22")),
                         max_date = c(as.Date("2001-10-27"),
                                      as.Date("2001-10-28"),
                                      as.Date("2002-10-28")))

 manager_DT

   Manager Store   min_date   max_date
1:    John     A 2001-10-22 2001-10-27
2:   David     A 2001-10-26 2001-10-28
3:   Steve     B 2001-10-22 2002-10-28
```

It's possible that there is more than one manager at store at a given time. Here, John and David have overlapping tenure at Store A (specifically on 2001-10-26 and 2001-10-27), but Steve is the only manager at store B.

Using data.table methods, I would like to merge `manager_DT` onto `DT` so that the desired output is:

```
DT
Store       Date       Manager
 1:     A 2001-10-22    John
 2:     A 2001-10-23    John
 3:     A 2001-10-24    John
 4:     A 2001-10-25    John
 5:     A 2002-10-26    John 
 6:     A 2002-10-26    David
 7:     A 2002-10-27    John
 8:     A 2002-10-27    David
 9:     A 2002-10-28    David
 10:     B 2001-10-22    Steve  
 11:     B 2001-10-23    Steve
12:     B 2001-10-24    Steve
13:     B 2001-10-25    Steve
14:     B 2002-10-26    Steve
15:     B 2002-10-27    Steve
16:     B 2002-10-28    Steve
```

Note here that there is only one manager column and whenever there are overlapping dates, the row is repeated (Here, two dates are repeated: 2001-10-26 and 2001-10-27 where BOTH John and David are managers at store A).

The idea here is that I want unique observations at the Date x Store x Manager level.

Thank you!

Comment: why did Manager David work 2002-10-26, 2002-10-27, 2002-10-28?

Comment: The idea is that he was the successor, but there was some overlap between the predecessor and successor for "hands on" training.

Comment: in the table `manager_DT` for John and David only 2001. How to determine on what dates they worked in 2002?

Comment: They worked from `min_date` to `max_date`, so all the dates in between. But the focus in on `DT`, where it may not contain all the dates in 2001 and 2002. The dates in that data.table is what I am interested in. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in creating the merged dataframe, a solution can be:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

manager_DT <- structure(list(Manager = c("John", "David", "Steve"), Store = c("A", 
"A", "B"), min_date = c("2001-10-22", "2001-10-26", "2001-10-22"
), max_date = c("2001-10-27", "2001-10-28", "2002-10-28")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

n <- nrow(manager_DT)

map_dfr(1:n, ~ data.table(
  Store=manager_DT$Store[.x],
  Date=seq(ymd(manager_DT$min_date[.x]),ymd(manager_DT$max_date[.x]),by="days"),
  Manager = manager_DT$Manager[.x]
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
library(dplyr)

DT <- structure(list(Store = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Date = c("2001-10-22", 
"2001-10-23", "2001-10-24", "2001-10-25", "2002-10-26", "2002-10-26", 
"2002-10-27", "2002-10-27", "2002-10-28", "2001-10-22", "2001-10-23", 
"2001-10-24", "2001-10-25", "2002-10-26", "2002-10-27", "2002-10-28"
), Manager = c("John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "David", 
"John", "David", "David", "Steve", "Steve", "Steve", "Steve", 
"Steve", "Steve", "Steve")), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

DT %>%
  group_by(Store,Date) %>% 
  mutate(Manager = paste(Manager, collapse = " and "))
```

Comment: Sorry, I get a "Error in paste(Manager, collapse = " and ") : object 'Manager' not found" when I run this code. Thank you!

Comment: Please, try the edited answer, which contains the data as well.

Comment: Thanks, this presents a solution. What I will do afterwards is simply repeat the number of rows by the number of "and"s, and then use the first name in the first observation, and the second name in the second observation. But is this approach robust if there are more than 2 managers? That is, if there happens to be three managers on the same date?

Comment: Yes, if there is more than 2 managers, the result will be: manager1 and manager2 and manager3... If you want to have the managers separated by comma, just replace `collapse = " and "` by `collapse = ", "`.